# AWS: download Cloudwatch alarms configured

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there a way to download all cloudwatch alarms configured and key configurations (name, enabled, Actions, Conditions) from the console? When I click on Alarms, I can see the list.

1. How can I download them to a csv file?
2. Also how can I list the action details. The console just shows "2 actions"

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: aws cli [describe-alarms](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudwatch/describe-alarms.html) ?

Comment: @samtoddler I was checking if there is a way to download it from console

Comment: I dont think from console you can do that, cli and api exists for such use cases.